# ASPX and PHP intergration with wordpress

Tags: php, asp.net, iis, web

Im more of an ASP.net programmer , however WordPress offers the basic ways to manage content and stuff on a webpage, unfortunately it runs on PHP only. I was wondering if there is any way to for one page say .Aspx page to contain both PHP script and ASP.net code to process the page into an html ?
I need the theme of Wordpress while I want some apps to work in asp.net code.

I have no idea of how to approach this, but i do have a server which supports both asp.net and php it would be a great help if anyone could point me to an article or answer that would allow both technologies to work on 1 page and render it and if by any chance i manage to do it would it affect when updating the wordpress ?

Is this in any way achievable or should I look for a .net version of word press or something similar ?

Comment: There are plenty of .NET alternatives to Wordpress. Integrating PHP and ASP.NET is a bad idea, ASP.NET is compiled which makes it very different from the way PHP functions, in most cases.

Comment: The cleanest C# integration I can think of, is creating a Web API or WCF service that you could call from PHP, but it depends on what you want to do.

Comment: What would be a good alternative in .net that would provide the source in vb hopefully ?

Yea i thaught of the web api too but the thing is i have an application already built with using asp.net controls and classes it would be a lot of work to turn all of that into webapi.

Answer (score 0):

While you can run PHP and ASP.NET on the same server, it'd be really difficult (or impossible) to use them both on the same page.

Instead, learn PHP or find a .NET based blog or CMS.